# Xamarin windows to mac build host on different network

Tags: macos, xamarin, build, visual-studio-2015, host

I'm trying to connect Xamarin(Visual Studio 2015) from my personal Windows 10 to the Mac of my company. Those 2 computers aren't on the same network.

So my question is:
Can I use a Mac as build host to build my code from a different network?

Thank !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer since I posted it ;)

Thank all for your help !

How to do? Let say that you have a friend who have a Mac machine and then you need it to compile your Xamarin Project from visual Studio

Download "Hamachi" where you want on the internet. You'll just need to create a account to use it, so do it :) It's free. Do it on both computer of course.

Create a network from Hamachi software from the machine 1
Join the network from Hamachi software from the machine 2

Now, follow [the tutorial given by Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) and you'll see, the Mac appears !

Answer (score 1):

With the new [Mac build system](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/), I don't believe that the machines are required to be on the same network, as long as the Mac is reachable from the Windows machine over port 22.

> The Windows computer must be able to reach the Mac via the network.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/): **The Windows computer must be able to reach the Mac via the network.**
When I'm away from work I use a VPN to achieve this. Check with your system administrator at work to see if you can use a VPN to get your Windows 10 machine connected to the business network (and thus, the Mac).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can SSH into the Mac from the Windows machine (there are several free apps such a Putty) you should be able to connect to that Mac from Xamarin in Visual Studio and use it as a Mac Build Host.